# SQL combined maximum value of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

i have a table with three columns

```
+------+------------+----------+
| item |    date    | sequence |
+------+------------+----------+
| a    | 30/11/2017 |        1 |
| a    | 30/11/2017 |        2 |
| a    | 31/12/2018 |        1 |
+------+------------+----------+
```

i would like to SELECT the maximum date and the maximum sequece of a date of an item, but

```
SELECT item, MAX(date), MAX(sequence of item-date-combination) FROM table GROUP BY item
```

does not work and

```
SELECT item, MAX(date), MAX(sequence) FROM table GROUP BY item
```

gives me the maximum sequence of all items and not of item-date-combinations.

like this:

```
+------+------------+----------+
| item |    date    | sequence |
+------+------------+----------+
| a    | 31/12/2018 |        1 |
+------+------------+----------+
```

What can I do?

so this seems to be it:

```
SELECT maxdate_q.item, maxdate_q.maxdate, maxseq_q.maxseq FROM (
    SELECT item, MAX(date) AS maxdate FROM table GROUP BY item) AS maxdate_q
LEFT JOIN (SELECT item, date, MAX(sequence) AS maxseq FROM table GROUP by item, date) AS maxseq_q ON maxseq_q.item = maxdate_q.item AND maxseq_q.date = maxdate_q.maxdate
```

Comment: provide your sample data and expected output

Comment: Please tag wth the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*  -- select whatever columns you really want.
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item order by date desc, sequence desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I think you should use more specific projection after your first `select` statement. Like this: `t.item, t.date, t.sequence`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `max()` window function

```
  SELECT item, MAX(date) over(partition by item) as Mxdate,
         MAX(sequence) over(partition by item) as MxSeq
     FROM table
```

Comment: Thanks Zaynul! That works for me under MS SQL SERVER

Comment: @Joachim you can use distinct

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL you can use correlated subquery :

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.seq = (select t1.seq
               from table t1 
               where t1.item = t.item
               order by t1.date desc, t1.seq desc
               fetch first 1 rows only
              );
```

Some other DBMS has different syntax to limit the rows such as SQL server uses `TOP` clause or `LIMIT` for MySQL.